# combine two n dimensional cell arrays into a n by n dimensional one

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I wonder how to do this in MATLAB.

I have `a={1;2;3}` and would like to create a cell array

```
{{1,1};{1,2};{1,3};{2,1};{2,2};{2,3};{3,1};{3,2};{3,3}}.
```

How can I do this without a for loop?

Comment: Do you really need a cell array? A 2D-array (matrix) seems more suitable (faster code, less memory)

Comment: @user3075021 so did you solve your problem with one of the answer below? If so please mark it as ACCEPTED. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`allcomb` from MATLAB File-exchange](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb/content/allcomb.m) to help you with this -

```
mat2cell(allcomb(a,a),ones(1,numel(a)^2),2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, using `kron` and `repmat`:

```
a = {1;2;3}

b = mat2cell([kron(cell2mat(a),ones(numel(a),1)) repmat(cell2mat(a),numel(a),1)])
```

Here square brackets [] are used to perform a [concatenation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html) of both column vectors, where each is defined either by `kron` or `repmat`.

This can be easily generalized, but I doubt this is the most efficient/fast solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using repmat and mat2cell

```
A = {1;2;3};
T1 = repmat(A',[length(A) 1]);
T2 = repmat(A,[1 length(A)]);
C = mat2cell(cell2mat([T1(:),T2(:)]),ones(length(T1(:)),1),2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) to help create unique permutations of pairs of values in `a` by unrolling both matrix outputs of `meshgrid` such that they fit into a `N x 2` matrix.  Once you do this, you can determine the final result using [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) to create your 2D cell array.  In other words:

```
a = {1;2;3};
[x,y] = meshgrid([a{:}], [a{:}]);
b = mat2cell([x(:) y(:)], ones(numel(a)*numel(a),1), 2);
```

`b` will contain your 2D cell array.  To see what's going on at each step, this is what the output of the second line looks like.  `x` and `y` are actually 2D matrices, but I'm going to unroll them and display what they both are in a matrix where I've concatenated both together:

```
>> disp([x(:) y(:)])

 1     1
 1     2
 1     3
 2     1
 2     2
 2     3
 3     1
 3     2
 3     3
```

Concatenating both vectors together into a 2D matrix is important for the next line of code.  This is a vital step in order to achieve what you want.  After the second line of code, the goal will be to make each element of this concatenated matrix into an individual cell in a cell array, which is what `mat2cell` is doing in the end.  By running this last line of code, then displaying the contents of `b`, this is what we get:

```
>> format compact;
>> celldisp(b)

b{1} =
     1     1
b{2} =
     1     2
b{3} =
     1     3
b{4} =
     2     1
b{5} =
     2     2
b{6} =
     2     3
b{7} =
     3     1
b{8} =
     3     2
b{9} =
     3     3
```

`b` will be a 9 element cell array and within each cell is another cell array that is `1 x 2` which stores one row of the concatenated matrix as individual cells.